# Copy fails in bash script even when I use `/bin/cp` and chmod 777 on the file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permissions, copy

I wrote a bash program to setup new Debian install's.... but I can't figure this problem/error out...... I can't get it to copy a .bashrc file to a new users `/home` directory even with 777 permissions.

Here are the declarations and setting of the variables:

```
 21 CURRENTDIR=/tmp/svaka
 22 BASHRC=.bashrc
 23 NANORC=.nanorc
 24 BASHRCROOT=.bashrcroot
```

---

Here are the files the program uses and they are in the same directory the program runs from:

```
$ls -sail /tmp/svaka
total 110
 21  1 drwxrwxrwx  3 root        root         1024 Sep 13 05:21 .
  2  3 drwxrwxrwt 13 root        root         3072 Sep 13 05:20 ..
 34  4 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         3250 Sep 11 23:27 .bashrc
 36  3 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         2517 Sep 11 23:27 .bashrcroot
 31  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          524 Sep 11 23:27 changePasswords.bash
 28  2 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         1235 Sep 11 23:27 checkSystem
 42  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         594 Sep 13 04:29 checuserpass.sh
 39  0 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root            0 Sep 11 23:28 cpSuccessCodes.txt
 25  8 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         8048 Sep 11 23:27 debianConfig_1.bash
 32 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10326 Sep 13 05:21 debianConfig_awsome.3.2.sh
 33  4 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         3971 Sep 11 23:27 debianConfig.sh
 35  9 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         8481 Sep 11 23:27 debianConfig_version.3.0.sh
 38  7 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         6970 Sep 13 05:07 debianConfigVersion3.1ERRORS.txt
340  1 -rw-r--r--  1 root        root  1024 Sep 13 05:13 .debianConfigVersion3.1ERRORS.txt.swp
 40 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
 41 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb.1
397 11 -rw-r--r--  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb.2
 43  3 drwxrwxrwx  6 root        root         3072 Sep 13 05:01 nanorc
 26  9 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         8833 Sep 11 23:27 .nanorc
 30  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          862 Sep 11 23:27 sources.list
 37  2 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         1723 Sep 11 23:27 ssh_config
 27  3 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         2573 Sep 11 23:27 sshd_config
 24  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          134 Sep 11 23:27 testing3892739.sh
 22  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          772 Sep 11 23:27 testing.sh
 29  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root           71 Sep 11 23:27 userlist.txt
 23  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root           71 Sep 11 23:27 users.txt
```

Here is the code:

```
300 for user in "$@"
301 do
302     if [ "$user" = root ]
303     then
304         continue
305     fi
306     sudo -i -u "$user" user="$user" CURRENTDIR="$CURRENTDIR" BASHRC="$BASHRC" bash <<'EOF'
307     echo "usersBashrc"
308     if /bin/cp -f "$CURRENTDIR/$BASHRC" "$HOME/.bashrc"
309     then
310         echo "Copy for $user \(bashrc\) succeeded!"
311         sleep 3
312     else
313         echo "Couldn't cp .bashrc for user $user"
314         exit 127
315     fi
316     chown $user:$user "$HOME/.bashrc" || exit 127
317     chmod 644 "$HOME/.bashrc"
318     wget https://raw.github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS/master/LS_COLORS -O "$HOME"/.dircolors
319     echo 'eval $(dircolors -b $HOME/.dircolors)' >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
320 EOF
321 done
```

I can get it to work if I add this line:

`chown $user:$user "$CURRENTDIR"/.bashrc`

just before I enter the `sudo`

**QUESTION:**

**My question is, shouldn't I be able to `copy` the `file` because it has 777 permissions set `read`,`write` and `execute` even though I'm not the owner?**

EDIT #1:

```
(root@HOST)-(15:11:52)-(/tmp/svaka)
$./system38.sh something71 something
+ for user in "$@"
+ '[' something71 = root ']'
+ chown something71:something71 /tmp/svaka/.bashrc
+ sudo -i -u something71 user=something71 CURRENTDIR=/tmp/svaka BASHRC= bash
usersBashrc
/bin/cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/tmp/svaka/'
Couldn't cp .bashrc for user something71


(root@HOST)-(15:11:54)-(/tmp/svaka)
$ls -sail
total 136
 21  1 drwxrwxrwx  3 root        root         1024 Sep 13 15:11 .
  2  3 drwxrwxrwt 13 root        root         3072 Sep 13 15:11 ..
 34  4 -rwxrwxrwx  1 something71 something71  3250 Sep 11 23:27 .bashrc
 36  3 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         2517 Sep 11 23:27 .bashrcroot
 31  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          524 Sep 11 23:27 changePasswords.bash
 28  2 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         1235 Sep 11 23:27 checkSystem
 42  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 something78 something78   594 Sep 13 04:29 checuserpass.sh
 39  0 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root            0 Sep 11 23:28 cpSuccessCodes.txt
 25  8 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         8048 Sep 11 23:27 debianConfig_1.bash
 32 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10426 Sep 13 14:32 debianConfig_awsome.3.3.sh
 33  4 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         3971 Sep 11 23:27 debianConfig.sh
 35  9 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         8481 Sep 11 23:27 debianConfig_version.3.0.sh
 38 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10661 Sep 13 09:06 debianConfigVersion3.1ERRORS.txt
 40 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb
 41 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb.1
397 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb.2
398 11 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb.3
340 11 -rw-r--r--  1 root        root        10658 Aug  3  2016 deb-multimedia-keyring_2016.8.1_all.deb.4
 43  3 drwxrwxrwx  6 root        root         3072 Sep 13 05:01 nanorc
 26  9 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         8833 Sep 11 23:27 .nanorc
 30  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          862 Sep 11 23:27 sources.list
 37  2 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         1723 Sep 11 23:27 ssh_config
 27  3 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root         2573 Sep 11 23:27 sshd_config
400  1 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root        root          793 Sep 13 15:11 system38.sh
 24  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          134 Sep 11 23:27 testing3892739.sh
 22  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root          772 Sep 11 23:27 testing.sh
 29  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root           71 Sep 11 23:27 userlist.txt
 23  1 -rwxrwxrwx  1 root        root           71 Sep 11 23:27 users.txt
(root@HOST)-(15:12:05)-(/tmp/svaka)
```

Comment: You say that you can't copy, but I don't see any error message in your post....

Comment: BTW, does it work if you don't use `cp`, but `cat "$CURRENTDIR/$BASHRC" >$HOME/.bashrc`?

Comment: @user1934428 I don't got any error message, it fails silently

Comment: @user1934428 The  `cat` works

Comment: You run `echo "Couldn't cp .bashrc for user $user"` if `cp` fails. Does not even that print?

Comment: @l0b0 Yes that get's printed if I recall but I'm sure I remember the exit code 127

Comment: If `cp` fails, there must be some error message, unless the `cp` utility itself is broken. Does /bin/cp work if you run the command explicitly from the command line? What exit code does /bin/cp return in your script? (You could print it in your error message, i.e. `echo "Couldn't cp (exit code $?) .bashrc for user $user"`. Also, remove the `-f` switch until you know what's going on here.

Comment: @user1934428 Will do update later

Comment: @user1934428 see the update for more information on the issue

Comment: `$BASHRC` is not defined (empty string see: `+ sudo [...] BASHRC= `), so you are running the command `/bin/cp -f "/tmp/svaka/" "$HOME/.bashrc"` instead of `/bin/cp -f "/tmp/svaka/.bashrc" "$HOME/.bashrc"`

Comment: 22 BASHRC=.bashrc

Comment: @somethingSomething : I don't understand. You said before that there were no error message, but on the update you post, we can see an error message from `cp`, and actually one, which clearly explains in plain English, why it could not perform the copying! So, what's the problem now?

Comment: @user1934428 I couldn't remember the error and didn't have the test enviroment  on hand when you where asking, I don't think there was one but this time I ran it without the `-f`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `-f`. Perhaps there was no subdirectory in `/tmp` when you executed it at that time. Also, you can see from the output of the script, that your variable `BASHRC` is empty, and in this case, your script won't run correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get it working if I change the quoting on the variable.....

`/bin/cp "$CURRENTDIR/$BASHRC" "$HOME/.bashrc"`

to

`/bin/cp "$CURRENTDIR"/"$BASHRC" "$HOME/.bashrc"`

I'm new to programming so I don't have any explanations for this.